# Google line chart(interactive) api - how we fill different background colors on specified areas

Tags: canvas, google-visualization

I have a requirement to fill background color horizontally in google line chart on specified area. I have looked all the api but didn't get a solution. Google image chart(I thinks it is deprecated) has some property but I am using interactive chart. I am just attaching an image  that I actually want.

Please help.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by using a ComboChart instead of a LineChart, and adding in some extra data series.  In your example, you would have 3 extra series with values of 800, 1000, and 1200 in every row.  Then you set the "series" option to make these "area" series that don't show up in the legend and don't spawn tooltips when you hover over them:

```
series: {
    0: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    1: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    2: {
        lineWidth: 0,
        type: 'area',
        visibleInLegend: false,
        enableInteractivity: false
    },
    3: {
        lineWidth: 0,
        type: 'area',
        visibleInLegend: false,
        enableInteractivity: false
    },
    4: {
        lineWidth: 0,
        type: 'area',
        visibleInLegend: false,
        enableInteractivity: false
    }
}
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/apH2B/

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, this is the graph that I want.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this work around, but I'd like to know how you set the color of the area, I would like to change them to specific ones. Thanks

Comment: You can set the color as one of the options for a series, using any valid HTML color string. Eg: https://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/apH2B/150/

Comment: Thank it worked like a charm, another quick one, how do i do to show values on each point on the line? I did some research and 'annotation' seems to be the way to go, but how do I implement it on your fiddle? 
here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xm6L6dnj/

Comment: You need to add an "annotation" role column to your data. This can be done manually if you want to have custom text for each point (see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/QjQNX/1707/) or you can define it in a DataView, and have the view calculate the annotations based on your data. The calculated column should come immediately after the column for your data: https://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/xm6L6dnj/1/

Comment: Hi, do you any idea how I can place the vAxis values in the middle of blocks instead of them being on the line?

Comment: @jNg what do you mean?

Comment: @asgallant the vAxis values sit on the horizontal lines, is there a way to move them so they can be in the middle on 2 lines?

Comment: The labels will always align with the values they represent; there is no way to change that behavior. You can control the number of gridlines, but not which values they appear on - they will always go from top to bottom, evenly spaced along the axis. Maybe the way to go would be to increase the range of the chart by 0.5 at the top and bottom, and use an appropriate number of gridlines?