# How do I set color for specific range in Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, css, graph

I'm new with charts, so I have created a google charts lines, and I need to change background color for some range as seen in the picture below.

my code so far is pretty basic and looks like this:

```
var options = {
    vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        },
        ticks: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100] 
    }
};
```

how can I change background color for example from 0 to 20 in my vAxis to look like this

[image: color in ranges]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some intensive research, I found the solution that lies on this link [Google line chart(interactive) api - how we fill different background colors on specified areas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18190744/4897281)