# How to change line color based on the value [google charts]

Tags: javascript

I have a chart to represent some temperatures of a specific place, I am using Google Chart tools (area chart), and Im trying to put a diferent color (orange) if the temperature is greater than 25 degrees

Javascript code

```
function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Data');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Temperatura ºC');

        data.addColumn({ type: 'number', role: 'annotation' });
        var array = JSON.parse('<%=jsonStringTemp%>');
        console.log(array);



      for(var i=0; i<array.length;i++){
        var array2=[];
          for (j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
              if (typeof array[i][j]==='string') {
                  if (j !== 0) {
                      array[i][j]=parseInt(array[i][j], 10)
                  }
              }
            array2.push(array[i][j])
          }
          data.addRow(array2)
        }

       console.log(data)
       var options = {
          title: 'Temperatura',
          hAxis: {title: 'Data',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
           vAxis: { minValue: 0 },
           series: {
               0: {

                   color: 'green'
               },
           },
           pointSize: 6
        };

;

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
      chart.draw(data, options); 
     }
```

output
[image]

Is it possible to do it? And How?

Comment: do you want something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44068132/how-do-i-set-color-for-specific-range-in-google-chart ?

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/lines