# Change Band color in Google ComboChart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I found an answer to my previous question about the chart here [fill background color horizontally in google line chart on specified area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18190744/4897281)

Now my problem is to change the area color[image: google combochart]

and the code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/apH2B/) (sorry embedding is causing error)

```
function drawChart () {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'x');
data.addColumn('number', 'y');
data.addColumn('number', 'color band 1');
data.addColumn('number', 'color band 2');
data.addColumn('number', 'color band 3');
data.addColumn('number', 'color band 4');
data.addColumn('number', 'color band 5');

var y = 50;
// fill with 100 rows of random data
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    y += Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 2));
    if (y < 0) {
        y = 10;
    }
    if (y > 100) {
        y = 90;
    }
    // make the colored bands appear every 20
    data.addRow([i, y, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]);
}

var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(data, {
    height: 400,
    width: 600,
    isStacked: true,
    vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100
    },
    series: {
        0: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        1: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            type: 'area',
            visibleInLegend: false,
            enableInteractivity: false
        },
        2: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            type: 'area',
            visibleInLegend: false,
            enableInteractivity: false
        },
        3: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            type: 'area',
            visibleInLegend: false,
            enableInteractivity: false
        },
        4: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            type: 'area',
            visibleInLegend: false,
            enableInteractivity: false
        },
        5: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            type: 'area',
            visibleInLegend: false,
            enableInteractivity: false
        },
        6: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            type: 'area',
            visibleInLegend: false,
            enableInteractivity: false
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `color` option in each series...

```
1: {
    color: '#f44336',  // <-- add color option
    lineWidth: 0,
    type: 'area',
    visibleInLegend: false,
    enableInteractivity: false
},
2: {
    color: '#2196f3',  // <-- add color option
    lineWidth: 0,
    type: 'area',
    visibleInLegend: false,
    enableInteractivity: false
},
...
```

area series are opaque by default
to see the true color, set --> `areaOpacity: 1`

```
1: {
    areaOpacity: 1,
    color: '#000000',
    lineWidth: 0,
    type: 'area',
    visibleInLegend: false,
    enableInteractivity: false
},
```

Comment: Hi, do you any idea how I can place the vAxis values in the middle of blocks instead of them being on the line?

Comment: you could provide your own labels (`vAxis.ticks`), with a set number of gridlines (`vAxis.gridlines.count`)...

Comment: can you show me with a fiddle please.
I have my ticks but they sit on the line, what I'm trying to achieve is to put the value in the middle. can you

Comment: that was just an idea, haven't actually tried -- will take a look when i have time later -- but would prefer you asked another question...